# Grails 2 Spring Security Plugin - Redirects to /login/denied after successful login

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have Spring Security Plugin successfully working for the most part in Grails 2.0.4.  If I go to page "localhost:8080/dashboard", I am redirected to the login screen.  When I login successfully, I am redirected to "/dashboard".

The problem I am having is if I just go to "localhost:8080/" without adding any controller to the URL. If I do this, then regardless of if I am successfully logged in, I am redirected to "/login/denied".  If I then at this point try to go to "/dashboard", it will work since I am a successfully logged in user.

My question is how to change the default screen I am redirected to after login.  Here's what I have tried.  Please let me know if there's anything I'm missing.  Everything seems to be working except for the actual redirecting.

Tried changing in URLMappings.groovy

```
static mappings = {
    "/"(controller: "dashboard")
}
```

Tried changing in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/dashboard'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/dashboard/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"],

    '/js/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"],
    '/css/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"],
    '/images/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"],
    '/login/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"],
    '/logout/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"]
]
```

Neither of these fixed the issue I explained above.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to add another entry to my interceptUrlMap:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"]
]
```

This allows the user to get to the '/' mapping in URLMappings and hence be forwarded to '/dashboard'. Without this mapping, there is no rule for '/', and we block that by default, so there is no chance to get to URLMappings to be forwarded.